# Fragment Custom Listview : Getting run time error

Tags: android, fragment

How to solve this run-time error ?
Thank you

**Error**
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main Process: com.example.arunabha.eshopping, PID: 1673
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

**BlankFragment1.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class BlankFragment1 extends ListFragment {
ListView mobileLV;
Adapter adapter;
ArrayList<SingleRowForMobile> list;
Context mContex;
public BlankFragment1() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank_fragment1, container, false);
    mobileLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobileLV);
    mContex = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    list = new ArrayList<SingleRowForMobile>();
    Resources res = mContex.getResources();
    int images[] = {R.drawable.apple_logo, R.drawable.blackberry_logo, R.drawable.samsung_logo, R.drawable.microsoft_logo, R.drawable.gionee_logo, R.drawable.micromax_logo, R.drawable.lenovo, R.drawable.asus_logo};
    String names[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.name_for_mobile);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        list.add(new SingleRowForMobile(names[i], images[i]));

    }
    adapter = new Adapter(mContex, list);
    mobileLV.setAdapter(adapter);
    mobileLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

}

**SingleRowForMobile.java**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class SingleRowForMobile {

    int images;
    String names;

    SingleRowForMobile(String names, int images) {
        this.images = images;
        this.names = names;
    }

    public int getImages() {
        return images;
    }

    public void setImages(int images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

    public String getNames() {
        return names;
    }

    public void setNames(String names) {
        this.names = names;
    }

}
```

**Adapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.arunabha.eshopping.R;
import com.example.arunabha.eshopping.SingleRowForMobile;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SingleRowForMobile> list;
    Context context;
    Adapter(Context c, ArrayList<SingleRowForMobile> listInput){
        context=c;
        list= listInput;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewGroup,false);

        TextView names = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView images = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);

        SingleRowForMobile temp = list.get(i);
        names.setText(temp.names);
        images.setImageResource(temp.images);

        return row;
    }
}
```

**fragment_blank_fragment1.xml**

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.example.arunabha.eshopping.BlankFragment1">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobileLV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**single_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="India"
            android:textSize="25sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your listview id from `mobileLV` to `android.R.id.list'`

Comment: this change is on `java` class ? what will be for `xml`.. please clear.

Comment: for both `java` and `xml`

Comment: Thanks a lottttttttttttt. :)